# issue regarding broadcast mac address

Tags: router, mac-address, arp, interface, broadcast

I read a line saying {Routes do not forward packets coming from **one interface** having **broadcast mac address**
**(FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF)**}

what is meant by one interface in that line?

if router cannot broadcast mac address then how does arp protocol works in router?

Does arp protocol works only with ethernet devices?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A router doesn't *forward* broadcasts to other networks/subnets (or between networks). It can very well receive and transmit them, however, so ARP isn't any problem.

IPv4 uses ARP for all MAC-based networks, most prominently Ethernet and Wi-Fi.